# Command not found when adding third parameters to a shell script

Tags: bash

Being on Ubuntu Server I am trying to write an automation script.

Here is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
    case $1 in
        -p | --port )           shift
                                PORT=$1
                                ;;
        -d | --domain )         shift
                                DOMAIN+=("$1")
                                ;;
        -l | --location )       shift
                                PATH=$1
                                ;;
        * )                     exit 1
    esac
    shift
done

echo "Parsing finished. List of domain is: "
for val in "${DOMAIN[@]}"; do
    echo " - $val"
done

echo "Generating -d domain list..."
for val in "${DOMAIN[@]}"; do
    domains="$domains -d $val"
done

echo "-d list is: $domains"

echo "Port is: $PORT."

echo "Location to save is: $PATH"

certbot certonly --standalone --standalone-supported-challenges http-01 --http-01-port $PORT $domains --cert-path $PATH
```

When ran with just two parameters, it works correctly.
When I specify the third parameter -l or --location, it gives:

```
cert-ggm.sh: line 35: certbot: command not found
```

I tried to rename the -l parameter to capital P, got the same result. The test echoes return correct value parse. What's the deal with the location parameter casting certbot command uncallable? Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's the result of using `PATH` for your user-defined variable - it's stomping on the system's executable search `PATH`

Comment: Change PATH to something else. for example 'location' or 'userpath' and see if this happens again

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, that was it. Please paste your comment as an answer and I will accept it.